# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> is missing after XML validate through receivelocation

Tags: biztalk

My incoming XML has  at the beginnig of the XML content.

However, after validate by the XSD through the receivelocation pipeline "XML Validate" and then sent to another folder through a pass-through pipeline, the "" is missing.

Any idea on the reason?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the assembler in the send pipeline is the part that controls XML encoding - if you send your message using XMLTransmit the XML Assembler will add your missing tag.  Obviously the pass-thru can't as it has to support non xml messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use pipeline with **XML Assempler** pipeline component.
XML Assembler pipeline component has some configurations including **AddXMLDeclaration** attribute.

Alternatively you can just use Send Port with XML Transmit pipeline (which is basically pipeline with XML Assembler only) and configure it directly in BizTalk Admin Console.

[image]